# How do I set the text value of label in GridView from click event of a Button in the same gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a button and an unbounded label(used for stock quantity level flag) in gridview.(Other columns are bounded). When  I click the button, I would like the label of the CLICKED ROW to show: in stock or out of stock based on condition. But now  All the label of ALL ROWS  display same thing.

The codes in the button clicked event checks for the quantity (condition) level and it is working ok. I was also able to find the label from the gridview in RowDataBound and to set the text property based on a quantity condition, but was unable to have this label and text property show up only in the clicked row.

```
Private Sub CartGrid_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles CartGrid.RowDataBound

 If (e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow) Then
        If ProdQtyInStock = 0 Then
            Dim lblCartQtyMsg As Label = CType(e.Row.FindControl("lblCartQtyMsg"), Label)
            lblCartQtyMsg.Text = "Out of Stock"

        End If
    End If
 End Sub
```

I want the label to ONLY show up at the row where the button is clicked.
Here is the code for the button click event:

```
Protected Sub btninc_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As  System.EventArgs)
   
    Dim PlusButton As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
    Dim Row As GridViewRow = DirectCast(PlusButton.Parent.Parent, GridViewRow)
    Dim productid As String =     CartGrid.DataKeys(Row.RowIndex).Value.ToString
    Dim lblcartSize As Label = CType(Row.FindControl("lblcartSize"), Label)
    Dim lblcartcolor As Label = CType(Row.FindControl("lblcartColor"), Label)
    Dim lblCartQty As Label = CType(Row.FindControl("LblCartQty"), Label)
    Dim cartQty As String
    If lblcartSize.Text.ToString = "NIL" And lblcartcolor.Text.ToString = "NIL" Then
        Dim colorid, sizeid As Integer
        sizeid = 1
        colorid = 1
        ProdQtyInStock = ShoppingCart.StockQtyChecker(productid, sizeid, colorid)
      If ProdQtyInStock = 1 Then
            ShoppingCart.UpdateQtyIncrement(productid, sizeid, colorid)
      ElseIf ProdQtyInStock = 0 Then
            ' show lblCartQtyMsg.Text = "Out of Stock"

        End If
        ' bindShoppingCart()
        ReCalculateShippingCost()
     Else
        Dim colorid, sizeid As Integer
        colorid = ShoppingCart.GetColorIDforProdCartDelete(productid, lblcartcolor.Text.ToString).colorid
        sizeid = ShoppingCart.GetSizeIDforProdCartDelete(productid, lblcartSize.Text.ToString).sizeid

        ProdQtyInStock = ShoppingCart.StockQtyChecker(productid, sizeid, colorid)

        If ProdQtyInStock = 1 Then
            ShoppingCart.UpdateQtyIncrement(productid, sizeid, colorid)
        ElseIf ProdQtyInStock = 0 Then

            'at show lblCartQtyMsg.Text = "Out of Stock"

        End If

        '' bindShoppingCart()
        ReCalculateShippingCost()
                 
    End If
    
    cartQty = lblCartQty.Text

End Sub
```

And here is the html for the button:

```
<ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="btnIncrement" runat="server"     CausesValidation="false" CommandName="Increment"
                 Text="+"   OnClick ="btninc_Click"  Font-Bold="True"     style="background-color:#fff; border :solid 1px #ccc"  />
        </ItemTemplate>
```

Here is how the cart look at the moment.

[image]

Comment: Please share the html and vb.net code of the button and its click handler.

Comment: @MohsinMehmood , I have updated my post.

Comment: When populating the GridView, add the ID of the item to the labelname. Then you'll have unique identifiable names of the labels and are able to change only one.